# Are all $*$-algebras with matrix representations projective?

Tags: category-theory, c-star-algebras, representation-of-algebras

If a complex unital $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ has a (bounded) matrix representation (i.e. a unital $*$-homomorphism) $$\psi:\mathscr{A}\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C}),$$ such that $\|\psi(a)\|_{\infty}<+\infty$ for all $a\in \mathscr{A}$, does $\psi$ necessarily factor through the $C^*$-enveloping algebra of $\mathscr{A}$, and does this mean every such $\mathscr{A}$ with this property is a projective object in the category of unital $*$-algebras?

Comment: I don't understand what $\|\phi(a)\|_{\infty}<+\infty$ is supposed to mean.  Is $\phi$ supposed to be $\psi$?  And what do you mean by this norm?  I can't see any reasonable interpretation that would not make this statement trivial...

Comment: I'm also not sure why you think this has anything to do with being a projective object.

Comment: Sorry yes, I do mean $\psi$ instead of $\phi$, and all I mean to say is that the matrices in the representations have finite singular values.

Comment: The reason I wondered about projective (though perhaps in this setting it's just trivial) is that for each representation $\psi$ I believe there must be a $*$-homomorphism from $\mathscr{A}$ to the $C^*$-enveloping algebra and a $C^*$-representation (i.e. a surjection) to $B(\mathbb{C}^d)\cong M_d(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: A $C^*$-representation need not be surjective.  In any case, this has nothing to do with being projective: projectivity says that *whenever* you have an epimorphism, you get other morphisms, not that there must exist certain epimorphisms.

Comment: ah, I see thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: (Also, there is no need to mention your norm condition: there is no such thing as a matrix with infinite singular values!)

Comment: Not all $^*$-algebras admit an enveloping C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: @Ruy for sure, I'm not claiming they do, factoring through the $0$ enveloping $C^*$-algebra just means there are no matrix representations. A $*$-algebra with no enveloping $C^*$-algebra can't have any non-zero matrix representations by the universal property right?

Comment: If $\{0\}$ is the enveloping algebra, then all is well regarding existence.  The failure to have an enveloping algebra is much worse than that.  Consider the algebra of polynomials in one variable.  It has lots of representations but no enveloping algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial from the universal property of the $C^*$-enveloping algebra: $M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is a $C^*$-algebra, so any homomorphism to it factors through the $C^*$-enveloping algebra.

This doesn't have anything to do with being projective, though.  For a simple example, let $\mathscr{A}=M_2(\mathbb{C})\times M_3(\mathbb{C})$.  This has matrix representations, but it is not projective: there is an epimorphism $\mathscr{A}\to M_2(\mathbb{C})$ (the first projection) which does not split since there are no homomorphisms $M_2(\mathbb{C})\to M_3(\mathbb{C})$.